# How to transform array and pass these data in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I fetched quiz data by following.

I'd like to transform by assigning each`answers` in each quizzes.

I guess I must use like `Foreach.push`. but I didn't figure out definite way..

```
const API_KEY="https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&type=multiple";
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const Quiz=require("../public/javascripts/quiz");

const finalResponse={
  results: []
};

module.exports={
    getQuiz:function(res){
      fetch(API_KEY)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {const quiz = new Quiz(json);
            res.send({
              quiz,
              Answers:quiz.getAnswers(1)
            });
        });
    }
};
```

I would like to transform `fetched data` by `constructing` following class and function.

```
console.log("quiz.js was loaded");

class Quiz {
   
    constructor(quizData){
        this._quizzes = quizData.results;
        this._correctAnswersNum = 0;
    
    
    getAnswers(index){
        const correctAnswer = this._quizzes[index-1].correct_answer;
        const incorrectAnswers = this._quizzes[index-1].incorrect_answers;
        
        const answers = incorrectAnswers.slice();
        answers.push(correctAnswer);
        
        for (let i = answers.length-1; i>0; i--){
            const rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1));
            [answers[i],answers[rand]]=[answers[rand],answers[i]];
        }
        return answers;
    }
    
}
module.exports = Quiz;
```

Now my output is following.

```
quiz {
  _quizzes: 
   [ { category: 'General Knowledge',
       type: 'multiple',
       difficulty: 'medium',
       question: 'After how many years would you celebrate your crystal anniversary?',
       correct_answer: '15',
       incorrect_answers: [Array] },
     { category: 'General Knowledge',
       type: 'multiple',
       difficulty: 'easy',
       question: 'What is on display in the Madame Tussaud&#039;s museum in London?',
       correct_answer: 'Wax sculptures',
       incorrect_answers: [Array] } ],
  _correctAnswersNum: 0 },
  Answers: [ '15', '20', '25', '10' ] }
```

My desired result is like following, i.e I would like to assign `Answers` in each quizzes.

If someone has opinion, please let me know.
Thanks

```
quiz {
  _quizzes: 
   [ { category: 'General Knowledge',
       type: 'multiple',
       difficulty: 'medium',
       question: 'After how many years would you celebrate your crystal anniversary?',
       correct_answer: '15',
       incorrect_answers: [Array]
       Answers: [Array]},
     { category: 'General Knowledge',
       type: 'multiple',
       difficulty: 'easy',
       question: 'What is on display in the Madame Tussaud&#039;s museum in London?',
       correct_answer: 'Wax sculptures',
       incorrect_answers: [Array]
       Answers: [array] } ],
  _correctAnswersNum: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Quiz {
   
    constructor(quizData){
        this._quizzes = quizData.results;
        this._correctAnswersNum = 0;

    }
    shuffle(answers){
        // so this is your shuffle function I didnt touch it
        for (let i = answers.length-1; i>0; i--){
            const rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1));
            [answers[i],answers[rand]]=[answers[rand],answers[i]];
        }
        return answers;
    }
    questions(){
       return  this._quizzes.map(quiz=>{
           // we map quizzes and merge correct answer and incorrect_answers
           let answers = this.shuffle([quiz.correct_answer,...quiz.incorrect_answers])
           // we are deleting incorrect_answers cause you don't want
           delete quiz.incorrect_answers
            return {
                ...quiz,
                answers,
            }
        })
    }
    
    
    
}
module.exports = Quiz;
```

and in your response

```
const API_KEY = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&type=multiple";
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const Quiz = require("./Quiz");

const finalResponse = {
    results: []
};

module.exports = {
    getQuiz: function (res) {
        fetch(API_KEY)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                const quiz = new Quiz(json);
                // this questions function is  processing questions as you wish
                console.log(quiz.questions())
                /* res.send({
                    quiz: quiz.questions(),

                }); */
            });
    }
};
```

Comment: Please add comments on your code, this helps the OP understand what you've done/changed.